# Refresh at Dartium raises a SocketException in websocket server

Tags: exception, websocket, dart, server-side

I've been testing websocket client and server with Dart. Basic concept comes from Seth Ladd's blog:

Server: http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/04/dart-server-supports-web-sockets.html

Client: http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/07/simple-dart-websocket-demo.html

Everything works as expected ie. server responds clients requests and if I open a new Dartium window both clients works. When I close a client window it closes related connection (onDone:).

If I hit the refresh-button in Dartium, server raises an exception and closes. The error code is: "SocketException: Write failed, (OS Error: server closed connection, errno 10053, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 8080".

Is this a bug or should I add some code somewhere? I can't find the place where this error comes from. The last message I can find by debuging is onDone: (same as when closing the client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be releated to [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13164). The comments mention that it should be fixed in next release on monday.

Comment: Thank you. I'll wait the new version and test it.